# How to get value from function in other script?

Tags: python

im running the script2 from script 1, but i cant get the value from script2 after run

sc1.py

```
import sys
import os
import sc2

os.system ('python sc2.py')
varB = sc2.main(varA)
print(varB)
```

sc2.py

```
def main(_argv):
    varA = 'Hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    app.run(main)
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

sc1 didnt print anything, how to do it?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: i need to get output from sc2 and print it or store it in sc1

Answer (score 1):

Your function in sc2 is not returning anything. So you are not getting any output in sc1. include a return statement in main.

Comment: im using return in sc2 still not print anything from sc1

Answer (score 1):

sc1.py

```
import sys
import os
import sc2

os.system ('python sc2.py')
varB = sc2.main("Hello")  #sc1 doesn't know varA
print(varB)
```

sc2.py

```
def main(_argv):
    varA = _argv
    return varA  # in order to actually return varA

if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    app.run(main)
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

Two points:

- You can't use `varA` in sc1.py, because sc1.py doesn't know it. It's defined in sc2.py
- You have to literally use the keyword `return` and whatever you want to return so that that value will be returned by sc2.py's `main` function and stored in `varB`.